# Unable to read Multi-select option set in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, custom-data-type

I am getting data from Dynamics CE with Data Factory and want to write it to an Azure Data Lake. But I encounter this Data Type error: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValueCollection is not supported.

I've checked the forums that say it is not supported and I checked this [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-dynamics-crm-office-365#data-type-mapping-for-dynamics) that says AttributeType.MultiSelectPicklist is not supported.

I was wondering if anyone has a workaround for retrieving columns with a multi-select option set value from Dynamics CE or is encountering the same issue.

Does it mean we can not use this data type in Dynamics CE if we want to let it flow through the Data Factory?

Kind Regards

Berry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After verifying with ADF team it is confirmed that this column type `OptionSetValueCollection` is not supported in ADF Dynamics CRM connector.

I’m not sure whether Dynamics side can do any column type conversion. 
Without existing connectors, the only way is to write some custom code which can implement the similar job as Dynamics CRM connector, where we can implement to fetch Option Set Value Collection column value. ADF supports to run customer application by using [custom activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity). This should work but requires additional custom development.

I would recommend you to please share your feedback/suggestion in ADF user voice forum: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-azure-data-factory.
All the feedback shared in this forum are monitored and reviewed by ADF engineering team. Please do share the feedback/suggestion link here once it is created, as it would help other users with similar idea to up-vote/comment on your feedback.

Ref Doc : [Data type mapping for Dynamics](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/connector-dynamics-crm-office-365#data-type-mapping-for-dynamics)

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/41148538-support-dynamics-multiselectpicklist-in-azure-data