# Azure Data Factory can not get multiselect option list from dynamics 365

Tags: azure-data-factory

Azure Data Factory Link Service has a Dataverse connector that allows you to extract data from Dynamics 365.

After extracting data we noticed that none of the multi-select fields were populating our Data Warehouse.

After doing some research we came across the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/358967/azure-data-factory-can-not-get-multiselect-option), which states that Azure Data Factory can not get multiselect option list from dynamics 365.

We noticed that the article was created in 2021.

Can someone let me know if it is still the case that Azure Data Factory can not get multiselect option list from dynamics 365.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see here:  [Unable to read Multi-select option set in Azure Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61098163/unable-to-read-multi-select-option-set-in-azure-data-factory)

And then go to docs quoted in that question, you will see that even though most attributes are supported, your required one is not:

The Dynamics data types AttributeType.CalendarRules, AttributeType.MultiSelectPicklist, and AttributeType.PartyList aren't supported.

What you can do is find a feature request most similar to your situation and upvote it and hope it will be implemented. You can also create your own request.

https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c?query=hubspot

Edit: I have also heard of using FetchXML for these attributes you can see if its works by making more research about this